# Replacing current date with String containing time in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, date, nsdate

I'm making an app where i get time from Parse as String e.g. "13:24" i need to prepare it to save in `CoreData` as Date, but replacing the time with this String to use it later in `fireDate` notification. What's the best approach to do this ? I should get the `currentDate()`, change it into string and somehow replace it with my timeString from `Parse` ?

Comment: you might want to take a look at the NSDataDetector!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this snippet to get todays date + custom time:

```
let time = "12:34"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"

var todayDateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
todayDateString.replaceRange(Range<String.Index>(start: todayDateString.endIndex.advancedBy(-5), end: todayDateString.endIndex), with: time)

let newDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(todayDateString)
```

Comment: Thanks ! Will it be compatible with `fireDate` to trigger notifications ?

Comment: `fireDate` for notifications is `NSDate?`, same as `newDate`, so it must be compatible :)